# Given a measure $\mu$ that satisfies $\mu((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$ for a specified increasing, right-continuous function $F$, find $\mu(\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: measure-theory

Define $F : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by

$$F(x) : = \begin{cases} 0 & \quad x < 1 \\ \frac{2x}{1+x} & \quad x \ge 1.\end{cases}$$

Then $F$ is increasing and right continuous. Suppose that $\mu$ is a measure that satisfies $\mu((a,b]) = F(b) - F(a)$, where $a<b$. Find $\mu(\mathbb{R}$).

My attempt:

Write $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{(-n,1-n]} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{(n-1,n]}$. Then $\mathbb{R}$ is a countable union of pairwise disjoint measurable sets. Hence, 
\begin{align*}\mu(\mathbb{R}) & = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{(-n,1-n]} \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{(n-1,n]}\right)\\
& = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{(-n,1-n]}\right) + \mu\left({\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty{(n-1,n]}}\right)\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{{F(1-n) - F(-n)}} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty{{F(n) - F(n-1)}}\\
& = 0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty{F(n)}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty{F(n-1)}\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{F(n)}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty{F(n)}\\
& = 0.
\end{align*}

However, I am not sure if I did this correctly.

Comment: I think your work was fine until you reindexed. Note that the $F(n) - F(n-1)$ sum is telescoping so you have $F(\infty) - F(0)$.

Comment: Oh! Great point. I always forget how often telescoping suns pop up in measure theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in that
$$
\mu(\mathbb R) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty F(n) - F(n-1).
$$
From here, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty F(n) - F(n-1) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n F(k)-F(k-1)\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} F(n) - F(0)\\
&= 2.
\end{align}